# Python - remove Windows folder

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I'm messing around in VM Box. I wanted to delete Windows folder (C:\Windows).
I tryed `shutil.rmtree()`, `os.rmdir()`, `os.remove()`, but still I got access denied. 
Is there anyway to do that, like Linux has force remove: `rm -rf 'Windows'`.
Account has Admin Priv.

Comment: Show an example with a *full stack trace*. If your user does not have permissions, your user does not have permissions.

Comment: 1) Why? 2) Seriously, why? 3) What user is your script running as?

Comment: Not a Windows expert, but I'm not sure if you can, as Windows implements mandatory locks that are not so easy to "force override".

Comment: Run a Linux instance and `rm -rf Windows` to your heart's content.

Comment: I did it. It's possible but takes a lot of time to figure out. Ultimately I had to delete that with CMD instead of python. It was funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active Admin Privs:

first of all, run CMD as Admin and type:

```
net user
```

the table will appear with users. Next check if real Admin is activated:

```
net user Administrator
```

and look for "ACCOUNT ACTIVE". If it says 'no', then use this command:

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
```

and make sure its acttive, so once again type `net user Administrator`.
Now switch to that Admin and perform your commands in Python.

It's interesting experiment, I hope you don't code some malware :D

Comment: `takeown /r /f folder` -> 
`cacls folder /c /G "ADMINNAME":F /T` -> 
`rmdir /s folder`